# Subversion repo upgrade makes repository unusable

Tags: svn

I recently upgraded my subversion server from 1.4.6 to 1.6.11.  The repos all seem to work correctly after this.  I then try to upgrade a repo by issuing the svnadmin update command, and it produces no errors and says the update is complete.  However, I am unable to open the repository after this.  I get the following error when trying to open the repo: Could not open the requested SVN filesystem.

I am using Apache, not SVNServe.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with with Apache - I needed to do some configuration changes.  Instead I simply installed VisualSVN Server and all my problems went away.

Answer (score 1):

Have you also upgraded your Subversion *client* to a corresponding compatible version? The client may not be able to understand the newest server filesystem format.

Comment: That would be true if he's doing direct local access to the repository (file url instead of network path).  That shouldn't be true if he's using a remote checkout, should it?

Comment: Yes, I just updated my client to 1.6.11 and I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

At risk of being downvoted, when we did the same upgrade, we also upgraded the hardware.  The permissions were not sorted out on the new filesystem and we received the same error.  You didn't mention any file system changes and without knowing what OS you're running this on, you could look there.

Comment: I'm running Windows Server 2003.  I'll check the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me, I needed to re-copy the mod_dav_svn.so modules into the apache modules directory.
see: 
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I ran into.  I didn't feel comfortable with making those edits so I changed to VisualSVN server, which provides a GUI interface.